# isValidationFailed default value

Tags: validation, jsf-2

What would the method `facesContext.isValidationFailed()` return after the Render Response Phase when the validation fails? It returns `false` for me in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will only return `true` when [`FacesContext#validationFailed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#validationFailed%28%29) has been called by the JSF validation internals or by your own code as follows:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed();
```

As far JSF internal code is concerned, only [`UIInput#processValidators()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#processValidators%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) and [`UIViewParameter#processValidators()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewParameter.html#processValidators%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) will implicitly call this method whenever a [`ValidatorException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/ValidatorException.html) has been caught.

If it returns `false` for you, then you're apparently doing validation in a non-standard way. For example inside the action method, while you should be using a real [`Validator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/Validator.html) for this.

Comment: After the render response phase(in the case where validation fails), I triggered an onchange on the input selectonemenu which calls a valueChangeListener in which I checked for isValidationFailed and it returns false, I tried getMessageList() which also returns 0

Comment: How do I check in my valueChangeListener if validation failed in this case?

Comment: The onchange would fire a brand new HTTP request. After all I think that you're achieving the particular functional requirement just wrong. Feel free to ask a new question wherein you describe the particular functional requirement in detail along with some relevant code of your failed attempt.